# how to using select datepart

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a SQL query like this

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column_date DESC) AS ROWID, * 
FROM 
    table_report 
WHERE 
    column_date = datepart(year,date)
```

Please *correct* if I'm wrong. I want *to take year* from datetime and then select top 1 row number by year

Comment: TOP 1 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY datepart(year,column_date) DESC) AS ROWID ....... where datepart(year,column_date) = datepart(year,date)

Comment: it's not running correctly. When I try, show error message Incorrect syntax near 'datepart'

Answer (score 1):

You can select the first row (in the order you provided) for every year by adding a partition to the windowing function, and then filter on just the first row of each year:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
     (PARTITION BY datepart(year,date) ORDER BY column_date DESC) AS ROWID,
     * 
    FROM table_report 
) X
WHERE ROWID = 1;
```